# Is SSL SAN certificate the right choice?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a site available under three national domains, let's say:

- www.mypage.no
- www.mypage.se
- www.mypage.dk

They use the same IP address.
I would like to secure it witha an SSL cerificate. I wonder wherher SAN certificate is the best choice for me? Let's assume I would use other subdomains in the future.

Here's an example offer:
https://comodosslstore.com/multi-domain-wildcard-ssl.aspx

Do I have to buy it for 4 domains:

- mypage.no,
- *.mypage.no,
- *.mypage.se,
- *.mypage.dk?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the wildcard cannot be in the end of the domain - you can't get `mypage.*` - so you will need to buy a separate certificate for each domain, and have the server select the correct certificate depending on the domain accessed by the request.  A SAN certificate, which specifies the domain as a Subject Alternative Name (SAN), is a good choice as use of the SAN to specify the domain is now the recommended method over the old method of specifying the domain as the Common Name (CN).